# How to use Google Sheets to autosort and rank fields?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a little bet game for the coming World Cup with my friends, using a Google spreadsheet.

So I first started to list the coming games:

[image]

*(data not relevant here, only to test!)*

Then I used nested `IF()s` to get the number of points of each team, for example Russia:

`=IF(C3>D3;3;IF(C3=D3;1;0)) + IF(C5>D5;3;IF(C5=D5;1;0)) + IF(D7>C7;3;IF(C7=D7;1;0))`

I also get the for and against goals:

`=C3+C5+D7`

`=D3+D5+C7`

Which helps me find all this data:

[image]

Now I want to sort and display these 4 teams, sorted by their number of points first, then their goal average, and then their amount of scored goals. And this is where I have no clue of what to use/how to use it...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a second sheet, or in another place on your original sheet, and put the =SORT() formula there:

```
=SORT(<your_range>, <by_column>)
```

I will be autosorted based on the current values in the range. It really doesn't get any simpler than that.